# Write XOR in haskell with functors

Tags: haskell, functor, boolean-logic, applicative

I'm relatively new to haskell and I just recently learned about Applicative Functors and I made this code for xor with only functors and boolean functions. I'm wondering if you guys can come up with a shorter solution (which I'm sure exists) with functors.

```
xor :: Bool->Bool->Bool
xor=(<$>) (not<$>) ((<*>).((((not<$>)<$>(&&))<$>)<$>((not<$>)<$>(&&)))<*>(||))
```

I know this probably isn't very good practice; it was more of a brain-teaser for me.

PS I hope this is allowed here

Comment: This belongs on http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Does it? I wasn't sure because it is language specific and I thought codegolf was more of a fun challenge type whereas here I am more trying to learn how to write shorter code with Functors.

Comment: you can make `xor` with `(||)` and `not`: `xor a b = not $ not (not a || not b) || not (a || b) ` which reduces to `(not .) . ap (ap . (((||) . not) .) . (. not) . (||) . not) ((not .) . (||))` wich can be written as `(not <$>) <$> (<*>) ((<*>) <$> (((||) <$> not) <$>) <$> (<$> not) <$> (||) <$> not) ((not <$>) <$> (||))`. Is this short enough for you?

Comment: `xor = (/=)`...

Answer (score 9):

Here is a solution which you could conceivably write by hand (and read, with a bit of guidance!). As @AJFarmar noted, we can write

```
xor a b = (a || b) && (not a || not b)
```

and I will use the rewrite he suggested as well, namely `a && b = not (not a || not b)`, though in the opposite direction he did:

```
xor a b = (a || b) && not (a && b)
```

You can follow the process below for other definitions, but this one is a particularly short starting definition.

Now we can pick out the chunks `a || b` and `a && b` and, instead of thinking of them as values of type `Bool` in an environment with `a :: Bool` and `b :: Bool`, transform them into a form where we think of them as values of type `Bool` with two `Applicative` "context" wrappers. Thus `(||) :: f (g Bool)` and `(&&) :: f (g Bool)`, where `f` and `g` are the particular `Applicative` instance `(->) Bool`. So we are in the partially translated state

```
xor = (||) && not (&&)
```

The only problem now is that the infix `&&` and the `not` expect pure `Bool` values, but are being handed doubly-wrapped `Bool`s. So we will lift them using double `liftA*` applications. Thus:

```
xor = liftA2 (liftA2 (&&)) (||) (liftA (liftA not) (&&))
```

There are other ways to spell this, too. I prefer the name `(<$>)` to `liftA`. Also, one can think of doubly-wrapped `Applicative`s as singly wrapped things with a more complicated wrapper, thus:

```
xor = getCompose (liftA2 (&&) (Compose (||)) (not <$> Compose (&&)))
```

Comment: Nice one! I couldn't find a way to write it by hand, but this is great!

Answer (score 6):

```
xor = (/=)
```

Why make it more complicated?

Comment: Haha, that's a good point, but for argument's sake, let's go with the functor route.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, this is really pointless and silly, but hey-ho.

First, I defined `xor` in terms of `&&`, `not` and `||`:

```
xor a b = (a || b) && (not a || not b)
```

Then if I use the fact that `(&&) a b = not (not a || not b)`...

```
xor a b = not ( not (not a || not b) || not (a || b) )
```

Which is low-level enough. Then, I ran it through [`pointfree`](https://evening-thicket-5270.herokuapp.com) to get this:

```
xor = (not .) . ap (ap . (((||) . not) .) . (. not) . (||) . not) ((not .) . (||))
```

Now, `ap` from `Control.Monad` is the monadic equivalent to `(<*>)`, and `(.)` is `(<$>)` in the function monad, so we can replace a few things:

```
xor = (not<$>)<$>(<*>)((<*>)<$>(((||)<$>not)<$>)<$>(<$>not)<$>(||)<$> not)((not<$>)<$>(||))
```

And voila, a really ridiculously stupid function that will achieve nothing special! Knock yourself out.

Comment: Erm, is this supposed to look like Perl code, or rather Brainfuck?

Comment: @leftaroundabout Aw yeah!